# return json with exception listener

Tags: symfony, exception

i want to create a empty custom exception and exception listener that return json response for that every time i throw my custom exception automatically my exception listener first called and return new json response without any exception page

i tried this code but i see always exception page without json response

this is my listener:

```
 class CustomExceptionListener
    {
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {

    $exception = $event->getException();
    if($exception instanceof TestException)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['code'=>JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN,'status'=>"missing api key!"],JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
}
```

exception:

```
class TestException extends RuntimeException
{
}
```

and this is my usage:

```
if (!in_array($token, $this->apiKeys)) {
      throw new TestException();
}
```

Comment: If you want to return such a response if the `TestException` is thrown, why does your code test for the opposite?

Comment: @NicoHaase what is opposite? im confused!!

Comment: `if(!$exception instanceof TestException)` - so the `JsonResponse` is only thrown when the given exception is **not** of type `TestException`

Comment: @NicoHaase im sorry post edited thats my fault when paste code. could you help me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Interesting. Have you checked whether your listener is called after all? How did you configure it?

Comment: @NicoHaase sounds it goes to my listener before and it is ok . but problem is i cant return json response in my exception . for example i can echo but cant return json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only return some new response from that handler, nothing happens. You have to replace the response that is currently in use in the event the following way:

```
<?php

class CustomExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {

        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof TestException) {
            $response = new JsonResponse(['code' => JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, 'status' => "missing api key!"], JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

A possible source for this is the Symfony documentation itself at https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html. The reason for this behaviour is that Symfony registers multiple handlers for that event, for example to write exceptions to a log. One of these parts ensures that a response is stored within the event, and later in the process the response is extracted from the event to be sent to the client (mainly by `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::handleException`).

The event is passed from listener to listener to keep track of multiple modifications, as the event itself holds more metadata than only the response.

Comment: that works :) . could you tell me why i have to to this instead return if it is extensive please give me the title of this or reference

Comment: @sinak good that it helps. I've attached more input in my answer - does this make it more understandable?